# Why is chloroform kept in dark coloured bottles?

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety, solvents

Why is chloroform ($\ce{CHCl3}$) kept in dark coloured bottles?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is quite easily found by typing "why is chloroform kept in dark bottles" into the Google search box.

Comment: @Todd lack of research on itself isn't a close reason. You can down vote instead.

Comment: @DEAD - My bad. VTC retracted. Thanks for the procedural reminder!

Comment: good point @DEAD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the presence of UV light, chloroform can be oxidized by atmospheric oxygen to phosgene ($\ce{COCl2}$), a toxic gas. The dark colored glass blocks UV light so that phosgene is not produced.